# Why is "stackoverflow" maintaining an active connection

Tags: windows, networking, port

I found this by pure accident and a little curious as to why is there 2 active connections, on 2 different ports present between my system and stackoverflow. I was doing something else with the network on my system, and when I used just `netstat` below is what I got.

[image]

I thought it must the number of open browser tabs or stackoverflow webpages that are open, but even when I close them and study after like 10 mins, these 2 still reflect. Even though they are in the `TIME_WAIT` which upon research I came to know, that my system has closed the connection and is waiting for remaining packets to flush out,but I still dont have a clue about these connections.

Any ideas?

Comment: The downvote (not mine) is that this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: so this question really should be going over to superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the "state" on those connections; [`TIME_WAIT` means that the connection is closed but that it hasn't aged out of the connection table yet](https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states). It's also not at all uncommon for those connections to stay `ESTABLISHED`, since browsers will generally use HTTP `Keep-Alive` to avoid having to open new connections for every page request.

Comment: so is it like even after I close the browser, the connection remains open for some time frame on all websites I open?

Comment: The connection isn't open; it's closing but isn't fully closed yet.

Comment: No. The connection is fully closed. The *port* is in a timeout state.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't 'maintaining' anything more than your browser is. Those connections are fully closed. The *port* is in `TIME_WAIT` state, which only lasts a couple of minutes after the final close. However there can be idle connections in `ESTABLISHED` state due to HTTP keep-alive.

Comment: someone is on a downvoting spree.

Comment: Two of these fearless seekers after truth now. Bizarre.

Comment: I flagged this question for moderator attention. But I dont know how to check for the proceedings.